# Orderby doesn't work like expected on custom query

Tags: meta-query, order

I have this custom query:

```
query_posts(  
  array ( 
    'orderby' => 'rr_recommends_count',
    'meta_key' => 'rr_recommends_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
  )
);
```

Which orders the posts like this:

9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, **11, 10,** 1 etc.

I see that the problem is that the meta_value field has a type of **longtext**.

How can I fix the sort without changing the meta_value field type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, never ever use `query_posts`. It breaks the main function and all plugins and functions relying on the main query object. For custom queries, use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` if aren't looking to paginate the query

As for the following line

```
'orderby' => 'rr_recommends_count',
```

I can tell you that `rr_recommends_count` is an invalid value to the `orderby` parameter.  Suspect that this is actually the key name, and the values are all numerical in that key, so you would use the `meta_value_num` value to the `orderby` parameter which is a valid value

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
```

Please see [Order and Orderby Parameters in `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: Replaced it with: 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' and works. I still don't understand why rr_recommends_count is invalid to the orderby parameter. orderby accepts strings and arrays.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the complete parameter. The new array syntax you are talking about is the new syntax where you can order by more than one value, say `title` and `date`. To fully understand thisn you will need to dig into a very messy `WP_Query` class which runs over 3000 lines of code :-)

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'rr_recommends_count',
     'order'   => 'DESC');
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Why must he use *try this*. Please add a proper explanation to your code and how it works.